# Rails - Conditional Query, with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a query like:

```
current_user.conversations.where("params[:projectid] = ?", projectid).limit(10).find(:all)
```

params[:projectid] is being sent from jQuery ajax. Sometimes that is an integer and the above works fine. But if the use selects "All Projects, that's a value of '' which rails turns into 0. which yields an invalid query

How with rails do you say search params[:projectid] = ? if defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may have mistyped the query a bit. `"params[:projectid] = ?"` shouldn't be a valid query condition under any circumstances.

In any case, you could do some sort of conditional statement:

```
if params[:project_id].blank?
  @conversations = current_user.conversations.limit(10)
else
  @conversations = current_user.conversations.where("project_id = ?", params[:project_id]).limit(10)
end
```

Although, I'd probably prefer something like this:

```
@conversations = current_user.conversations.limit(10)
@converstaions.where("project_id = ?", params[:project_id]) unless params[:project_id].blank?
```

Sidenotes:

1. You don't have to use `.find(:all)`. Rails will automatically execute the query when the resultset is required (such as when you do `@conversations.each`).
2. Wherever possible, try to adhere to Rails' snakecasing naming scheme (eg. `project_id` as opposed to `projectid`). You'll save yourself and collaborators a lot of headaches in the long run.

Thanks but if the where query has lets say 3 params, project_id, project_status, ... for example, then the unless idea won't work. I'm shocked that Rails doesn't have a better way to handle conditional query params

EDIT: If you have multiple params that could be a part of the query, consider the fact that `where` takes a hash as its argument. With that, you can easily build a parameter hash dynamically, and pass it to `where`. Something like this, maybe:

```
conditions = [:project_id, :project_status, :something_else].inject({}) do |hsh, field|
  hsh[field] = params[field] unless params[field].blank?
  hsh
end

@conversations = current_user.conversations.where(conditions).limit(10)
```

In the above case, you'd loop over all fields in the array, and add each one of them to the resulting hash *unless* it's blank. Then, you pass the hash to the where function, and everything's fine and dandy.

Comment: Thanks but if the where query has lets say 3 params, project_id, project_status, ... for example, then the unless idea won't work. I'm shocked that Rails doesn't have a better way to handle conditional query params

Comment: @AnApprentice: See my edited answer for how you could handle that.

Comment: Last option worked like a charm... Can we call this magic of Ruby? This is great and extremely functional!

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand why you put:

```
where("params[:projectid] = ?", projectid)
```

if you receive params[:project] from the ajax request, the query string shouldn't be:

```
where("projectid = ?", params[:projectid])
```

intead?

And if you are receiving an empty string ('') as the parameter you can always test for:

```
unless params[:projectid].blank?
```

I don't think i undestood your question, but i hope this helps.